# Resize img before uploading?

Tags: javascript, canvas, resize, blob

Good morning,

I am currently developing a reporting module. Currently I can transfer 3 photos in the session storage but the size is limited (2M). I would like a resizing before uploading the photo. Here is the code for a photo (I ask for 3):

```
function readFile1() {
    if(this.files[0].size > 8097152){
       alert("L'image est trop lourde, essayer de la réduire. (max: 2Mo/image)");
       this.value = "";
    };
    $('#contentPhoto2').css("display", "flex");

    if (!this.files || !this.files [0]) return;

    const selectedFile = this.files[0];

    const img = new Image();
    img.src=URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile);
    img.onload = () => {
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        let width = img.width;
        let height = img.height;

        if(width > height){
            if (width > maxWidth) {
                height *= maxWidth / width;
                width = maxWidth ;
            }
          else {
            if (height > maxHeight) {
                width *= maxHeight / height;
                height = maxHeight ;
            }
          } 
           canvas.width = width;
           canvas.height = height;
           ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

           canvas.toBlob(
            (blob) => {
                const selectedFile = new FileReader();
                selectedFile.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
                    document.querySelector("#previewPhoto1").src = e.target.result;
                    $("#b64Photo1").val(e.target.result);
                });
            selectedFile.readAsDataURL(blob);
            },
            "image/jpeg",
            0.95

            );
        }

    }

}

// Lecture de l'input[type="file"] n°3

function readFile3(){
    if(this.files[0].size > 2097152){
       alert("L'image est trop lourde, essayer de la réduire. (max: 2Mo/image)");
       this.value = "";
    };

    if (!this.files || !this.files [0]) return;

    const selectedFile = this.files[0];

    const img = new Image ();
    img.src=URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile);
    img.onload = () => {
        const canvas = document.createElement ("canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        let width = img.width;
        let height = img.height;

        if (width > height) {
            if (width > maxWidth) {
                height *= maxWidth /width ;
                width = maxWidth;
            }
            else {
                if (height > maxHeight){
                    width *= maxHeight / height;
                    height = maxHeight ;                
            }
        }
        canvas.width = width;
           canvas.height = height;
           ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

           canvas.toBlob(
            (blob) => {
                const selectedFile = new FileReader();
                selectedFile.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
                    document.querySelector("#previewPhoto3").src = e.target.result;
                    $("#b64Photo3").val(e.target.result);
                });
            selectedFile.readAsDataURL(blob);
            },
            "image/jpeg",
            0.95
            );
        }

    }

}


// Lance les fonctions sur les différents input[type="*file"].
document.querySelector("#photo1").addEventListener("change", readFile1);
document.querySelector("#photo3").addEventListener("change", readFile3);



/*
 * Stock les valeurs dans le stockage de session
*/

function signalementStorage() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('photos', JSON.stringify ({
        images : {
            'image1': $('#b64Photo1').val(),
            'image3': $('#b64Photo3').val(),

        }

    }));
}
```

L'image n'apparait pas et n'est pas uploadé, je ne peux pas la récupérer dans la page suivante.

Merci

Comment: Hello any Helps ?